# How do I resolve a  "load 3:0000065432" error message?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, steam, technical-issues

I tried loading Skyrim from Steam and everything was working fine, but after I press play on the game window with the Dovahkiin in the background, I get the message:

> load 3:0000065432

How can I fix this?

Comment: have you tried to [verify the integrity](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=2037-QEUH-3335) of your game files yet?

Comment: Thank you! I went to that link, and followed the instructions provided, and now my game works. :D

Comment: @yx. *gentle prod to post as an answer*

Comment: @yx. Still not posted as answer! Do it soon or I might just so it is marked as answered.

Comment: @Lemmings19 be my guest :)

Answer (score 1):

There are a variety of things you can do in order to try and resolve error 51/Load 3:0000065432;

- Verify game integrity
- Run the game as administrator
- [Downgrade your graphics driver](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showpost.php?p=29280137&postcount=4)
- Uninstall any custom textures/mods you have installed
- Reinstall the game

Answer (score 0):

https://bethesda.net/community/topic/135897/application-load-error-3-0000065432

> This error is often caused by an antivirus blocking a program on your computer. You can troubleshoot this issue by following the steps below:
>
> - Uninstall any custom textures or mods you have installed.
> - Run the game and Steam as administrator:
>
>   1. Right-click on the Steam shortcut or launcher and select Properties.
>   2. Navigate to the Compatibility tab.
>   3. Check the Run this program as an administrator checkbox.
>   4. Click Apply, then OK.
> - Verify the integrity of your Game in Steam:
>
>   1. Open Steam.
>   2. From the Steam Library, right-click on Skyrim and select Properties.
>   3. Navigate to the Local files tab.
>   4. Click Verify integrity of game cache and allow the process to complete.
> - Exclude Skyrim and Steam in your antivirus program. FSecure, in partricular, has been known to cause this error.

Comment: Note that this also matches the official answer for the same issue for Fallout 4 -- http://help.bethesda.net/app/answers/detail/a_id/32406